Angular 17: Lazy-Loading A Shared Component
(Most of the answers I've found are very out-of-date and don't deal with standalone components).
In my Angular application, I have multiple shared components that are standalone. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to make them lazy load if they aren't a route that uses loadComponent() and import() in the routes definitions file.
So, I have this in my application:
src
- main
  - app
    - modules
      - shared
        - components
          - shared-component1.component.ts
          - shared-component2.component.ts

Is there a relatively easy way in modern Angular versions to lazy-load a shared, standalone Angular component?

You can achieve that with deferrable views. To lazy load the component, just place it inside a @defer block in the template like the following:
@defer {
  <shared-component1 />
}

Make sure that the component is only loaded via @defer across the whole project, and not eagerly loaded somewhere else. (Thanks @Matthieu Riegler for pointing that out)

Also make sure this component isn't eagerly loaded elsewhere !

Another approach that could work, is to make the component standalone, or make a new module that declares and exports it.
It will be tree-shaken out of the main bundle by default (assuming it isn't imported there), and be included with any lazy modules that import it.
You can verify this using webpack-bundle-analyzer, to make sure your new component module isn't included in your main bundle.
This approach has always worked well for my shared components.
